# Django models. What is faster: filter by string or by integer?

Tags: django, performance, django-models

`models.py`:

```
class ReviewString(models.Model):
    REVIEW_TYPES = (
        ('bad', 'bad'),
        ('ok', 'ok'),
        ('good', 'good')
    )
    review_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=REVIEW_TYPES)
    # other fields here


class ReviewInteger(models.Model):
    REVIEW_TYPES = (
        ('bad', -1),
        ('ok', 0),
        ('good', 1)
    )
    review_type = models.IntegerField(choices=REVIEW_TYPES)
    # other fields here
```

Both of the tables (`ReviewString` and `ReviewInteger`) contains same data in data base.
I want to know, if there is any perfomance difference between these two strings:

```
ReviewString.objects.filter(review_type='ok')
ReviewInteger.objects.filter(review_type=0)
```

So, should i use `ReviewString` or `ReviewInteger`?

Comment: I think integer but I prefer string because it's easy to read and understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer indexes are faster than varchar ones.

Although, as long as you have an index on your review_type column, the performance and speed difference its really not significant and therefore you shouldn't really make the decision on performance aspects.

Maybe you should be more careful on choosing the one that fits better your python code rather than the one faster at the database level.

Regards

Comment: thank you, now i can use strings without being afraid of bad perfomance)